# Angular Material layout conflicts with my original CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I just started to learn Angular Material. The problem is that after I include the Angular Material script, my original CSS gets messed up. The `margin-top` simply doesn't work, no matter what value I set.

Could anyone help me?

My login form CSS is like this:

```
#login {
width: 300px;
height: 240px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 100px;
background: #EEEEEF;
padding: 30px 30px 0px 30px;
}
```

The `margin-top` conflicts with Angular Material. How should I solve that?

Comment: Can you place a url or try out code snippet so that i can test it?

Comment: the only reason I can think of is the CSS coming from angular-material has higher [specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/#css-specificity-an-overview) than your CSS.

Comment: Have you tried using    ` margin-top: 100px !important;`   to your style.

Comment: @DanielAbraham don't teach bad practices :)

Comment: It's almost not a good idea to use !important. This is bad engineering by the creators of the Angular Material. It forces users to add their own !important modifiers to override it, and it limits the options for overriding it via JavaScript.

But, it's useful to know how to override it, if you sometimes have to. @tanmay

Comment: @DanielAbraham use CSS Specificity instead of `!important`. [Reference](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know)

Answer (score 1):

try to keep important for margin-top:100px !important;
If not solved try to keep your code so that we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Give it a position:absolute?

Or am I completely missing the point..typing to pass minimum